# increment value is not working on click using jquery

Tags: jquery

This is the code I added in my script. It doesn't seem to be working though.

```
$('.add').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents('.row').find('.box-row').append('<div class="box">    <span>0</span></div>');
});

var i=0;
$('.box').each(function(i){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        i++;
        $(this).parent().find('span').html(i);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, the `i` parameter of the anonymous function you provide to `each` as it is preventing access to the `i` variable in the higher scope. Also, the `.box` elements are appended dynamically, so you need to use a delegated event handler which renders the use of `each()` moot anyway. Try this:

```
var i = 0;
$('.box-row').on('click', '.box', function() {
    i++;
    $(this).parent().find('span').html(i);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qLfnns39/)

Note that the above code will amend the counter in all `span` elements added, no matter how many there are. If you only want to change the counter in the clicked `.box` then you would need to amend your logic slightly:

```
$('.box-row').on('click', '.box', function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var count = $el.data('count') || 1;    
    $el.find('span').html(count);
    $el.data('count', ++count);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qLfnns39/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`i` is already an external var.

```
var i=0;
$('.box').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        i++;
        $(this).parent().find('span').html(i);
    });
});
```

remove `i` from `.each(function(i))` and you should be ok. i think the error is there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove i from function(i), as you have already declare this.
Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $('.box').each(function(i){
        $(this).on('click', function(){
            i++;
            $(this).parent().find('span').html(i);
            console.log(i);
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
<span></span>
<input type="button" value="click me" class="box" />
</div>
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/ku5vq0zh/2/